# How to use POSIXLY_CORRECT in grep?

Tags: bash, grep, environment-variables, posix, gnu

There is a variable [POSIXLY_CORRECT](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-POSIXLY_005fCORRECT) in Bash

> POSIXLY_CORRECT
>
> If this variable is in the environment when Bash starts, the shell
>   enters POSIX mode (see Bash POSIX Mode) before reading the startup
>   files, as if the --posix invocation option had been supplied. If it is
>   set while the shell is running, Bash enables POSIX mode, as if the
>   command
>
> ```
> set -o posix
> ```
>
> had been executed.

I was told that some options of `grep` are not POSIX and so I confirmed in [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6 for `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html). So I checked the [GNU grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) and found:

> *grep* comes with a rich set of options: some from POSIX and some being GNU extensions. Long option names are always a GNU extension,
>   even for options that are from POSIX specifications. Options that are
>   specified by POSIX, under their short names, are explicitly marked as
>   such to facilitate POSIX-portable programming. A few option names are
>   provided for compatibility with older or more exotic implementations.

And it also mentions:

> [2.2 Environment Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Environment-Variables)
>
> The behavior of grep is affected by the following environment variables.
>
> **POSIXLY_CORRECT**
>   If set, grep behaves as POSIX requires; otherwise, grep behaves more like other GNU programs. POSIX requires that options that follow file names must be treated as file names; by default, such options are permuted to the front of the operand list and are treated as options. Also, POSIXLY_CORRECT disables special handling of an invalid bracket expression. See invalid-bracket-expr.

Using the part *Long option names are always a GNU extension, even for options that are from POSIX specifications* I said: let's try the variable POSIXLY_CORRECT against that.

So I did try with something that is not POSIX:

```
$ echo "HELLO" | grep --ignore-case 'hello'
HELLO
```

But to my surprise it also works setting it:

```
$ echo "HELLO" | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 grep --ignore-case 'hello'
HELLO
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't a set POSIXLY_CORRECT make `grep` not recognize a long option name?

The same occurs if using an option (for example `-C`) that is not POSIX:

```
$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 grep -C 2 '2' <<< "1
2
3"
1
2
3
```

As well as doing all the same running `set -o posix` before.

Comment: `grep` is an external program, it's not part of the shell.

Comment: Try `export POSIXLY_CORRECT`

Comment: @cdarke When you put a variable assignment at the beginning of the command it exports it automatically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be a better question for unix.stackexchange.com. It's about the design of a specific Unix program, not programming.

Comment: @Barmar: I know it should.  That was an attempt to rule out the possibility of a typo.

Comment: @Barmar well, I disagree. This is about _software tools commonly used by programmers_, which is detailed in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: `grep` is a software tool used by all Unix users, not specific to programmers. Programmers also use the `ls` command to list the directory containing their source files, but that doesn't make it on-topic here.

Comment: @fedorqui Shells make this a gray area, because in no other language do you spend most of your effort simply running other programs. IMO, the tools in question are things like build tools, compilers, text editors (if the question is about configuration for a specific language or programming in the editor's scripting language). Here, the question is simply about how to use `grep`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the GNU `grep` manual:

> `POSIXLY_CORRECT`
>
> If set, `grep`  behaves  as  POSIX  requires;  otherwise,  `grep`
>                 behaves  more  like  other GNU programs.  POSIX requires that
>                 options that follow file names must be treated as file names;
>                 by  default,  such  options  are permuted to the front of the
>                 operand  list  and  are  treated  as  options.   Also,  POSIX
>                 requires that unrecognized options be diagnosed as "illegal",
>                 but since they are not really against the law the default  is
>                 to diagnose them as "invalid".  `POSIXLY_CORRECT` also disables
>                 `_N_GNU_nonoption_argv_flags_`, described below.

This means that the only thing that setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment does for GNU `grep` is that it's not allowed to rearrange options that occur after the filename so that the are placed at the front.  It doesn't make it not take non-POSIX command line flags.

So let's try that:

```
$ ggrep "hello" myfile -v

$ env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 ggrep "hello" myfile -v
ggrep: -v: No such file or directory
```

(GNU `grep` is called `ggrep` on my BSD system)

The part about "unrecognized options" in the manual is what GNU `grep` does by default, i.e. the `-g` flag will be diagnosed as "invalid" under both with `POSIXLY_CORRECT` and without. Since e.g. `--ignore-case` is a *valid option* (though not POSIX), this is not diagnosed as "invalid" with `POSIXLY_CORRECT`.

In general, check the documentation for external utilities for how they behave under `POSIXLY_CORRECT` (if they care at all). The `bash` manual can only tell you how the shell and its built-in commands are affected by this environment variable.

Comment: You beat me by a narrow margin.  Maybe emphasize that the documentation for Bash only applies to Bash, and that the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` setting does for `grep` exactly what the `grep` manual says it does.

Comment: The [grep spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) incorporates the [utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) by reference, and the latter say that "Each option name should be a single alphanumeric character[...]" so this is arguably a POSIX violation anyway.  However, GNU has never adhered that strictly to POSIX in the first place.  POSIXLY_CORRECT was always a portability device, and was never intended to provide full POSIX compliance.

Answer (score 3):

First, in general the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable which is used by a couple of GNU tools and library functions is an attempt to be more posixly correct, it does not guarantee that GNU tools behave strongly according to POSIX.

---

GNU `grep` itself is not reading the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable at all when it comes to option parsing. GNU grep is using the glibc function `getopt_long` to parse it's options. This function respects the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable but just in a limited way. Check [`man getopt_long`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long):

> **POSIXLY_CORRECT**
>
> If this is set, then option processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument is encountered.

... and the source code of GNU `grep`

This behaviour is the same for all programs which are linking against glibc and using `getopt_long`. It is not specific to `grep`.

Comment: So it was my misunderstanding on this variable. I thought POSIXLY_CORRECT would make me travel back in history to the POSIX `grep` version, which is not.

Comment: No it is not. I guess it is always a trade off of code complexity, performance, backwards compatibility and yes, posix conformity :)