# grep treating leading * as literal character?

Tags: grep

I recently noticed this behavior of GNU grep:

```
$ grep '*' <<< 'aaa'; echo $?
1
$ grep '*' <<< 'aa**aa'
aa**aa
```

In the second command, both asterisks are output highlighted, meaning they're considered "matched" by `grep`.

As far as I know, GNU grep assumes POSIX BRE (as `grep -G`) without any options, and a single asterisk is an *invalid* BRE. However, it appears like grep treats a leading asterisk as a literal one:

```
$ grep '*?' <<< 'aaa***???bbb'
aaa***???bbb
     ^^
```

This may appear intuitive to non-regexers, but I'm finding it strange. I have gone through `man grep` but can't find any related description about this behavior.

Why doesn't `grep` complain about this invalid regex but instead treat inappropriately positioned metacharacters as literal ones?

Comment: as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605463/how-to-use-posixly-correct-in-grep , GNU grep is not going to behave as per POSIX standards, even if you use POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable

Comment: `?` is not a metacharacter in BRE, so `grep '?*' <<< 'aaa???bbb'` is matching `?` character zero or more times

Comment: @Sundeep So OK I was wrong about the question mark, but what about the asterisk (I'm sure this time)?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441485/using-wildcard-at-the-beginning-of-grep-expression-affects-the-output is the closest I've found.. see answer + comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [POSIX BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03), `*` is required to match a `*` character when it's found:

> - In a bracket expression
> - As the first character of an entire BRE (after an initial '^', if any)
> - As the first character of a subexpression (after an initial '^', if any);

So `grep '*'`, `grep '^*'`, `grep '\(*\)'`, `grep '\(^*\)'`, `grep '[*]'` are all required to match on a literal `*`.

It's different in [POSIX EREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03) (as used with `grep -E`), where the behaviour is *undefined* if `*` (or `+`, `?`, `{x,y}`) is used in those contexts (which allows some implementations to implement some extended `(?...)`, `(*...)` operators for instance, though most actually report errors instead)